# Converting document string attribute into GeoJSON

Tags: json, mongodb

This should be a simple question but for some reason I can't find examples of this while searching. Currently I am importing a CSV file into mongo which is creating to me documents like this

```
{
 attributeA: "string"
 atributeB:1
 coordinates: "[102.0, 0.5]"
}
```

I need to make geographical queries using the coordinates field, for that I need to convert the coordinates string into a proper json object, but I am not entirely sure how to do that in Mongo

Comment: How does the CSV file look like?

Comment: Same structure as I mentioned in the post (
 "string",1,"[102.0, 0.5]")

Comment: The `mongoimport` tool was designed to perform import only, not data manipulation, so your best is to roll your own custom data importer to translate the coordinates string to a proper GeoJSON object.